# Drawing with paintComponent in JScrollPanel

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm actually stuck on something strange. I have a JFrame with a JScrollPane containing a jPanel far larger than the actual screen. I draw squares in colums and I want theses squares to go over the right border of the jPanel. (So that they will appear as you scroll to the right.) But the squares painted with the method paintComponents just stop at the visible ViewPort of the JScrollPane.

Here is my code for the JScrollPane inside of the JFrame:

public void initComponents(){

```
    mainPanel = new DrawPanel(dim);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;


    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(mainPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    jsp.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
    jsp.setViewportView(mainPanel);
    jsp.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(20);
    jsp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(dim.width,dim.height -taskBarSize));
    jsp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(dim.width,dim.height -taskBarSize));
    jsp.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(dim.width,dim.height -taskBarSize));
    this.getContentPane().add(jsp, gbc);
    this.getContentPane().revalidate();
    this.getContentPane().repaint();




}
```

And here is my JPanel class :

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

```
private Dimension dim;
private Integer numberPanels = 7;
private Double startPointX;
private Double startPointY;
private Double heightRow;
private Double heightPanel;


public DrawPanel(Dimension d) {
    this.dim = d;
    //this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    calculateStartPoint();
}

public void calculateStartPoint() {


    startPointX = (dim.getWidth() / 10) * 1;
    startPointY = (dim.getHeight() / 10) * 1;
    heightRow = (dim.getHeight() * 0.8) / numberPanels;
    heightPanel = heightRow - 10;
    double colums = 366/numberPanels;
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(heightRow *((int)colums + 1)), dim.height ));
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int)(heightRow *((int)colums + 1)), dim.height ));

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 366; i++) {

        // Si c'est le dernier d'une colonne
        if (i%numberPanels == 0 && i != 0) {
            g.fillRect(startPointX.intValue(), startPointY.intValue(), heightPanel.intValue(),
                    heightPanel.intValue());
            startPointX = startPointX + heightRow;
            startPointY = startPointY - ((numberPanels -1) * heightRow);

            // Si c'est encore dans la meme colonne
        } else {
            g.fillRect(startPointX.intValue(), startPointY.intValue(), heightPanel.intValue(),
                    heightPanel.intValue());
            startPointY = startPointY + heightRow;
        }

    }


}

}
```

At startup:

[image]

When I move the scrollPane:

[image]

Also, on resizing everything disapreas. Also I had to see that when scrolling back, the already painted squares disapeared, as if everything out of screen disppears.

Thanks for anybody who has some time for this.

Comment: Please create and post a valid [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to recalculate the starting points every time the painting is done. Else the variables keep increasing unnecessarily. So add two lines:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // should be protected
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // need to re-initialize variables within this
    startPointX = (dim.getWidth() / 10) * 1;
    startPointY = (dim.getHeight() / 10) * 1;
```

FYI, in the future, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question. For example, this is the MCVE that I made out of your code, code that now can be copied, pasted and run by *anyone*:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Foo02 extends JPanel {
    private DrawPanel mainPanel;
    private Dimension dim = new Dimension(200, 200);

    public Foo02() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents() {
        mainPanel = new DrawPanel(dim);
        // !! this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // !!
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(mainPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        jsp.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
        jsp.setViewportView(mainPanel);
        jsp.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(20);
        jsp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(dim.width, dim.height));
        jsp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(dim.width, dim.height));
        jsp.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(dim.width, dim.height));
        add(jsp, gbc);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Foo02 mainPanel = new Foo02();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo02");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private Dimension dim;
    private Integer numberPanels = 7;
    private Double startPointX;
    private Double startPointY;
    private Double heightRow;
    private Double heightPanel;

    public DrawPanel(Dimension d) {
        this.dim = d;
        // this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        calculateStartPoint();
    }

    public void calculateStartPoint() {
        startPointX = (dim.getWidth() / 10) * 1;
        startPointY = (dim.getHeight() / 10) * 1;
        heightRow = (dim.getHeight() * 0.8) / numberPanels;
        heightPanel = heightRow - 10;
        double colums = 366 / numberPanels;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (heightRow * ((int) colums + 1)), dim.height));
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int) (heightRow * ((int) colums + 1)), dim.height));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // should be protected
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // need to re-initialize variables within this
        startPointX = (dim.getWidth() / 10) * 1;
        startPointY = (dim.getHeight() / 10) * 1;

        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 366; i++) {
            // Si c'est le dernier d'une colonne
            if (i % numberPanels == 0 && i != 0) {
                g.fillRect(startPointX.intValue(), startPointY.intValue(), heightPanel.intValue(),
                        heightPanel.intValue());
                startPointX = startPointX + heightRow;
                startPointY = startPointY - ((numberPanels - 1) * heightRow);
                // Si c'est encore dans la meme colonne
            } else {
                g.fillRect(startPointX.intValue(), startPointY.intValue(), heightPanel.intValue(),
                        heightPanel.intValue());
                startPointY = startPointY + heightRow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my good I was a real morron, I totally forgot this!! Thanks a bunch, I was so focused on the paintComponents method that I forgot to reinitialise those points!

Comment: @nightslit: you're welcome! Note the edit to answer that shows a [mcve] that I created to help figure out the problem. In the future, you'll want to include a valid MCVE with your question to make them easier to answer. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the correction, I will do this next time.